# VBA ScaleHeight 2003 vs 2013

Tags: excel, vba, scale

I have created an Excel file (XLS) in Excel 2003 and added the following macro:

```
Sub test()
Dim p As Shape
   Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\test.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, -1, -1, -1, -1)
   p.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   p.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

When I run this macro, the picture is inserted and the height is scaled. When I open the sheet in 2013 and run the macro, both the height **and** width are scaled.

I can't find any documentation on the internet that explains this difference.

Has anyone encountered this also? And if so, what would be the solution. Should I check the application.version and do some conditional encoding?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You know what `LockAspectRatio` means? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194696.aspx

Comment: Yes. I added this line to see whether it would make a difference, but no: 2003 only scales the height, 2013 both height and width.

Comment: `p.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse`

Comment: Hi Axel: this is interesting: changing the LockAspectRatio does have an effect on 2013. In 2003 it doesn't matter if I set this value or not. It seems like LockAspectRatio defaults to true in 2013 and has no effect in 2003